# Unicode filenames on Windows in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unicode, windows-7, internationalization

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
Dir.new(path).each do |entry|
    puts entry
end
```

The problem comes when I have a file named こんにちは世界.txt in the directory that I list.
On a Windows 7 machine I get the output:

```
???????.txt
```

From googling around, properly reading this filename on windows seems to be an impossible task. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're out of luck with pure ruby (either 1.8 or 1.9.1) since it uses the ANSI versions of the Windows API.

It seems like Ruby 1.9.2 will support Unicode filenames on Windows. [This bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1685) has 1.9.2 as target. According to [this announcement](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/206049) Ruby 1.9.2 will be released at the end of July 2010.

If you really need it earlier you could try to use [FindFirstFileW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418.aspx) etc. directly via `Win32API.new` or [`win32-api`](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/win32-api/).

Comment: FWIMC, the bug is still not fixed in the latest 1.9.2

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem & just figured out how to get the entries of a directory in UTF-8 in Windows. The following worked for me (using Ruby 1.9.2p136):

```
opts = {}
opts[:encoding] = "UTF-8"
entries = Dir.entries(path, opts)
entries.each do |entry|
  # example
  stat = File::stat(entry)
  puts "Size: " + String(stat.size)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use `Dir.glob` instead of Dir.entries. But it only works with * parameter. It does not work when passing a path (c:/dir/*). Tested in 1.9.2p290 and 1.9.3p0 on Windows 7.

There are many other issues with unicode paths on Windows. It is still an [open issue](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1685). The patches are currently targeted at Ruby 2.0, which is [rumored](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-2-0-release-schedule-announced-roll-on-2013-5536.html) to be released in 2013.